# Rest API credentials issues in power bi service

Tags: rest, powerbi, business-intelligence, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

We have created a power bi report in power bi desktop and we made the incremental refresh configurations and we, for the first time, published our report to pbi service:

[image]

[image]

The normal refresh button works fine in PBI Desktop, but The problem is that when trying to set a Scheduled Refresh or connecting our dataset to the a Gateway we face credential issues like shown below:

[image]

And when editing the credentials we faced this error:

[image]

And when it comes to adding a datasource to the GateWay here's the issue:

[image]

Please Help Us!!!

Comment: Your account is it pro?

Comment: @FabianoCarvalho Yes it's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that I was trying to connect to a localhost web api, but once I connected to the live one everything starts to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Could you change your data source authentication method to Windows, and provide your credentials?